# pm2: unknown option `--run-as-user'

Tags: pm2

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/deploy-ghost-updates-with-git/) on working with git and ghost and they use pm2 to manage the ghost process, but after I do local changes and push them with `git push web` I get error:

```
pm2: unknown option `--run-as-user'
```

These are the contents of my `hooks/post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export NODE_ENV=production
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/ghost git checkout -f

cd /var/www/ghost
pm2 kill
npm install --production
chown -R ghost:ghost /var/www/ghost
pm2 start index.js --run-as-user ghost --name ghost # THIS MIGHT BE DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--run-as-user` option was removed in **0.12.0** version. Use `-u` or `--user` e.g

```
pm2 start index.js -u ghost --name ghost
```